# How to sort a list from ascending to decsending discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, discord.py, bots

```
   def ext():
       for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
           if filename.endswith('.py'):
               client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
               print(f'{filename} was loaded successfully!')
       print('------------------------------------')
       for guild in client.guilds:
           print(f'Server Name: {guild}, Members: {guild.member_count}')
       print('------------------------------------')
```

This is my extension function the runs on_ready. It prints out all of the servers the bot is in. I am wondering if there is a way to make it show from most members to least?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation. 
Sorting a sequence in reverse order is a trivial look-up, not a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
for guild in sorted(client.guilds, key=lambda guild: guild.member_count, reverse=True):
    print(f'Server Name: {guild}, Members: {guild.member_count}')
```

Comment: Thanks I changed guild.member_count to -guild.member_count so It was sorted the way I wanted it to be!